# Dynamically merge N rows into one row

Tags: google-sheets, merge

I am using google sheets and have the following format,

[image]

I want to get `Col3` from `Col1` and `Col2`. As you can see the spaces after `Col1` elements are dynamic and that is why its hard to keep track of how many rows to append.

I would have added some code, but I have no idea where to begin. Kindly give me some direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult to do without a sample spreadsheet but there is a chance that this works if you put it in cell `C2` and drag it down column `C`

```
=IF(A2="",,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(B:B,LOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER(ROW(A:A),A:A<>""))=LOOKUP(ROW(A2),FILTER(ROW(A:A),A:A<>"")))))
```

[Formulas used](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en):
FILTER()
ROW()
TEXTJOIN()
LOOKUP()